# Events with FlowDocumentPageViewer WPF

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

Needed some help.

1. Is there are any events while we change the pages in the FlowDocumentPageViewer
2. is there are any events while we zoomIn/zoomOut in the FlowDocumentPageViewer

Best,
Bala.

Answer (score 1):

**Are there any events while we change pages in FlowDocumentPageViewer?**

Yes.  FlowDocumentPageViewer.MasterPage changes values whenever you change pages.  Since it is a DP you can just bind your own DP to it, and handle the PropertyChangedCallback on your DP.

**Are there any events while we zoom in/out in FlowDocumentPageViewer?**

Yes.  FlowDocumentPageViewer.Zoom changes values whenever you change the zoom.  Since it is a DP you can just bind your own DP to it, and handle the PropertyChangedCallback on your DP.

---

Example:

```
<FlowDocumentPageViewer
  Zoom="{Binding MyZoom, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,MyControl,1}}"
  MasterPage="{Binding MyMasterPage, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,MyControl,1}}"
  ...
```

Where `MyZoom` and `MyMasterPage` are DependencyProperties defined on MyControl.

Answer (score 0):

For the master page you can handle the PageDisconnected event inside the DocumentPageView in the FlowDocumentPageViewer control template. This event will be raised when the master page is changed. Inside the event handler you can compare the DocumentPageView.PageNumber with your stored page number value.